# SQL Server NULL constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, constraints

Is is possible in SQL Server 2008 to create such a constraint that would restrict two columns to have NULL values at the same time? So that

```
Column1 Column2
NULL    NULL   -- not allowed
1       NULL   -- allowed
NULL    2      -- allowed
2       3      -- allowed
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_ColumNulls CHECK (Column1 IS NOT NULL OR Column2 IS NOT NULL)
```

As part of the create

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
 Column1 int NULL,
 Column2 int NULL,

 CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_ColumNulls CHECK (Column1 IS NOT NULL OR Column2 IS NOT NULL)
)
```